# Stuck on number of arguments for If statement

Tags: formula

I'm getting the error  Incorrect number of parameters for function 'if()'. Expected 3, received 1, but I can't figure out where I haven't provided those parameters - I have my statements and the 'else' is 'Jee Hye'.

```
if (

( 
    RecordType.Name = "Event" && Has_Deliverables__c = FALSE &&  
or( 
    ISPICKVAL(Event_a_mystery_to_attendees__c, "Yes"),  
    ISPICKVAL(Event_selected_by__c,"Mystery Selected"))), 
      'CHANDLER AND KRISTEN',  
if (
 (
   RecordType.Name = "Event" && Has_Deliverables__c= FALSE)&& 
 or( 
   ISPICKVAL(Event_a_mystery_to_attendees__c,"No"),  
   ISPICKVAL(Event_selected_by__c,"Customer Selected"))),
      'CHANDLER',
if (
   RecordType.Name = "Subscription", 
      'SLACK PICKS'),

        'Jee Hye'
  )
```

Comment: Never mix and match styles between `AND`/`OR` vs `&&`/`||`. Pick one only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you should do when trying to debug formulas is to indent it as if it were code.

Doing that should look like this

```
IF(
    (
        RecordType.Name = "Event" && Has_Deliverables__c = FALSE &&  
        OR( 
            ISPICKVAL(Event_a_mystery_to_attendees__c, "Yes"),  
            ISPICKVAL(Event_selected_by__c, "Mystery Selected")
        )
    ), 
    'CHANDLER AND KRISTEN',  
    IF(
        (
            RecordType.Name = "Event" && Has_Deliverables__c= FALSE
        )&& 
            OR( 
                ISPICKVAL(Event_a_mystery_to_attendees__c,"No"),  
                ISPICKVAL(Event_selected_by__c,"Customer Selected")
            )
    ),
    'CHANDLER',
     IF(
         RecordType.Name = "Subscription", 
         'SLACK PICKS'
     ),
    'Jee Hye'
)
```

This makes things like mismatched parenthesis a whole lot easier to spot.

In this case, there is a pretty clear issue with the final nested `IF()`.

```
IF(
    RecordType.Name = "Subscription", 
    'SLACK PICKS'
),
'Jee Hye'
```

It doesn't match up perfectly with the error you're reporting, but it is an issue. "Jee Hye" should be inside of that final `IF()`, and there shouldn't be a comma after the final `IF()`.

i.e.

```
IF(
    RecordType.Name = "Subscription", 
    'SLACK PICKS',
    'Jee Hye'
)
```

You're also prematurely closing the second `IF()` when you've only specified the condition (and not the "then" or "else" parameters), which is the source of this error.

```
IF(
    <conditions omitted>
),
'CHANDLER',
IF(...)
```

Which ought to be

```
IF(
    <conditions omitted>
    'CHANDLER',
    IF(...)
)
```

Some additional closing thoughts:

- `<boolean> = true` can *always* be simplified to `<boolean>`, and `<boolean> = false` to `NOT(<boolean>)`
- Mixing boolean operators (`&&`, `||`, `!`) and boolean functions (`AND()`, `OR()`, `NOT()`) is syntactically valid, but is more prone to semantic (logical) errors. You should pick one style, and stick to it. Consistency is king.

Comment: Thanks, Derek - this is helpful. I updated the syntax to be all functions instead of a mix - but I still don't quite understand why I needed to move Jee Hye into the last IF since I want that to be the 'else' parameter for the entire statement.

Comment: @JBradshaw with `IF(<condition>, <then>, <else>)`, the final `<else>` part in the chain (and we do need to chain `IF()`s in formulas) is the fallthrough/default value for the overall expression. It does look a little funky, but that's how it works (and it's difficult to convey that better in text alone). The `IF()` function _always needs you to specify all 3 parameters_.

Comment: Appreciate the clarification, Derek - one of these days I'll get it easier :)